# Multi threaded server - how to synchronize shared resources

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, server

I'm implementing a server-client-solution. In detail, the server side is implemented in java and should be multithreaded. The client side will be an android app, which connects to the java serversocket.

I've already done some work for this project, but now I'm facing a problem I can't find a solution for. I've researched a lot, but I can't find any helpful answer.

This is the server code:

```
public class Server implements Runnable{

protected int serverPort = 8001;
protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
protected boolean isStopped = false;
protected Thread runningThread = null;
protected Vector<WorkerThread> threads;
protected volatile Vector<Player> players;
protected Vector<Game> games;

protected synchronized Vector<Player> getPlayers()
{
    return players;
}

public Server(int port)
{
    this.serverPort = port;
    this.threads = new Vector<WorkerThread>(1);
    this.games = new Vector<Game>(1);
    this.players = new Vector<Player>(1);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Server starting");
    synchronized (this)
    {
        this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
    try
    {
        openServerSocket();
        while (! isStopped())
        {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try
            {
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                if (isStopped())
                    System.out.println("Server stopped.");
                break;
            }
            this.threads.add(new WorkerThread(clientSocket));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        for (int i=0;i<this.threads.size();i++)
            this.threads.get(i).stopThread();
        System.out.println("Server stopped");
    }
}

private void openServerSocket()
{
    try
    {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        System.out.println("Server is listening");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port "+this.serverPort,e);
    }
}

public synchronized void stop()
{
    this.isStopped = true;
    try
    {
        this.serverSocket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
    }
}

private synchronized boolean isStopped()
{
    return this.isStopped;
}

public class WorkerThread extends Thread
{
    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    protected ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    protected ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    private Player player;
    protected ReadThread readThread;

    public WorkerThread(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


//          synchronized (players)
//          {
            int playerId = 0;
            if (getPlayers().size() > 0)
                playerId = getPlayers().get(getPlayers().size()-1).id + 1;
            player = new Player(playerId,"NoName");

            getPlayers().add(player);
//          }

        try
        {   
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("WorkerThread and streams created!");

            readThread = new ReadThread(ois, this);
            System.out.println("ReadThread created!");

            while (this.isInterrupted() == false)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("WorkerThread is waiting ...");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            readThread.stopThread();

            try
            {
                oos.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {
                ois.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("WorkerThread and streams destroyed!");
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void stopThread()
    {
//          synchronized (players)
        {
            getPlayers().remove(player);
        }
        System.out.println("Player removed from list");
        this.interrupt();
    }

    public void sendPackage(DataPackage p)
    {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(p);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void processPlayerPackage(PlayerPackage p)
    {

    }

    private void processStringPackage(StringPackage p)
    {
        String msg = p.data;
        System.out.println("Incoming command: " + msg);

        //Kommandos auswerten
        if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Start new game"))
        {
//              games.add(new Game(p));
//              sendMsg("New game created!");
//              System.out.println("New game created");
        }
        else if (msg.toLowerCase().startsWith("playername="))
        {
            String name = msg.substring("playername=".length());
            player.name = name;
            sendPackage(new StringPackage("Hallo "+name));
            System.out.println("Player send name");
        }
        else if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Get running games"))
        {
//              sendPackage(new StringPackage("Hallo "+name));
//              sendMsg("Running games following:");
//              sendObject(games);
//              wr.sendPackage(p);
            System.out.println("Player requested running games");
        }
        else if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Get player count"))
        {
//              synchronized (players)
            {
                sendPackage(new StringPackage("Playercount="+players.size()));
            }
            System.out.println("Player requested player count");
        }
        else if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Get active players"))
        {
//              sendMsg("Active players following:");
//              synchronized (players)
            {
                for (int i=0;i<getPlayers().size();i++)
                    System.out.println("Player" + i + ": "+getPlayers().get(i).name);
                sendPackage(new PlayerPackage(getPlayers()));
            }
            System.out.println("Player requested active players");
        }
        else if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Start game"))
        {
            System.out.println("Player wants to start a game");
        }
        else if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Logout"))
        {
            this.stopThread();
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Command could not be processed: " + msg);
    }

    protected void processPackage(DataPackage p) {
        if (p instanceof StringPackage)
        {
            processStringPackage((StringPackage) p);
        }
        else if (p instanceof PlayerPackage)
        {
            processPlayerPackage((PlayerPackage) p);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

}

public class ReadThread extends Thread
{
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private WorkerThread thread;

    public ReadThread(ObjectInputStream in, WorkerThread r)
    {
        this.thread = r;
        this.in = in;
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (this.isInterrupted() == false)
        {
            try {
                DataPackage p = (DataPackage) this.in.readObject();
                if (p != null)
                    thread.processPackage(p);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                thread.stopThread();
                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (EOFException e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ReadThread has stopped!");
    }

    public synchronized void stopThread()
    {
        this.interrupt();
    }
}

}
```

The problem is, that every WorkerThread seems to have its own status of the shared variables from the beginning of the server. For example, if a connection is established, there will be a new Player created in the WorkerThread and added to the Vector `players` from the Server. After this I send an Object with my ObjectOutputStream containing this Player Vector. For this data transfer i've created a new Class which implements `Serializable` called `PlayerPackage`.

```
public class PlayerPackage extends DataPackage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5206233636684028091L;
protected Vector<Player> data;

public PlayerPackage(Vector<Player> v)
{
    this.data = v;
}

public Vector<Player> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Vector<Player> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

If there comes in another connection, there will be created another Player object and added to the vector. So the players vector now contains two players. For testing I print the content of the vector before sending it out. This output is correct as it prints the two players for both connections. But if i create and send a new `PlayerPackage` to both connections, only the second and newer connection gets the two players. The first connection still gets a PlayerPackage with only one Player (the first player)

I've already tried to fix this with `synchronize` and `volatile` as you can see, but none of my tries helped.

I know this is a lot of code to read, but I think that I should provide you with detailed information for my specific problem.

Comment: First things first: don't use `Vector`. This is 2015. Also, use an `ExecutorService`, not raw `Thread`s.

Comment: Also, I believe you are the victim of a misundertsanding; it is NOT because, say, a `Runnable` does not take arguments when it `.run()`s that _your own_ `Runnable` implementation cannot. You seem to want all variables shared (or not) by all threads visible to everyone; don't do that! Give any worker of yours what it needs to work and nothing else -- as constructor arguments if need be.

Comment: Your Server class should declare an ExecutorService (as mentioned above) but NOT be Runnable.  Create a *separate* class that implements Runnable and then submit those jobs to the executor service.